# Ajax retorna erro após modificar htaccess

Tags: php, ajax, htaccess

Eu modifiquei o `.htaccess` com uma regra para a url ser passada como parametro GET e eu tratar tudo na `index.php`:

```apache
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [QSA]
```

Após essa alteração, o ajax (post) abaixo retorna como erro e não completa minha requisição:

```js
$("#criar").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax
       ({
            type : 'post',
            url : "http://www.xxxx.com.br/criar-pagina-ajax.php",
            data: 
            {
                nomepagina: $('#nome-pagina').val(),
                idcategoria: $('#id-categoria').val(),
                idpaginacurtir: $('#id-pagina-curtir').val(),
                youtube: getYoutubeId($('#youtube').val()) 
            },
            dataType : "json",
            beforeSend : function()
            {
                $("#mensagem").html('Verificando...');
            },
            success : function(data)
            {
                $("#mensagem").html(data.mensagem);
                if (data.cod == 1)
                {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Não estou conseguindo resolver este problema, creio que a URL está sendo reescrita com a regra do `.htaccess` e o POST não é reconhecido no `criar-pagina-ajax.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, o problema neste caso é a URL.
Vejo como solucão mudar a sua URL:

De:
`http://www.xxxx.com.br/criar-pagina-ajax.php`

Para:
`http://www.xxxx.com.br/criar-pagina`

Assim sendo, quando você dividir a sua URL que você está pegando pela variável `$_GET['params']` no `index.php` verá que a requisição é a de criar a pagina, e poderá chamar a função que está escrita no script `criar-pagina-ajax.php`

**EDIT**
Um exemplo basico no `index.php`:

```
$requisicao = explode("/", $_GET['params']);
$parametro = $requisicao[count($requisicao) - 1]; // $parametro = "criar-pagina"
if ($parametro == "criar-pagina") {
    // Faça alguma coisa
}
```

Comment: Mas o `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` não deveria dar prioridade ao `criar-pagina-ajax.php`, considerando que ele exista?

Comment: Bom, o que posso afirmar é que as regras `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` e `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` verificam se a requisição é um diretório ou um arquivo comum ( txt, css, js, etc.. ( O .php não é influenciado, pois creio que ele é considerado como algo diferente de arquivo ) ) respectivamente. Caso ele passe por essas 2 condições, ele vai pra última regra, onde a requisição é enviada para o `index.php` dentro da variável `$_GET['params']`

Comment: Hm, eu imaginava que ele pegasse php.